# How to spinner popup background color change

Tags: android, xml, android-spinner

I want to make the spinner opening box black but it doesn't work.

Style code:

```
<style name="Spinner">
    <item name="android:popupBackground">@color/colorBlack</item>
    <item name="android:paddingStart">0dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingEnd">0dp</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorWhite</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundTint">@color/colorWhite</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">20sp</item>
    <item name="android:spinnerMode">dropdown</item>

</style>
```

Spinner code

```
            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatSpinner
                style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Spinner.Underlined"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:entries="@array/array_name"
                android:theme="@style/Spinner">

            </androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatSpinner>
```

My device android version 5(lolipop)

Answer (score 0):

Th solution i found is you have put custom item layout  with having background color you want in adapter.check out below

```
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View vista = convertView;       

        // layout for spinner widget

        if (vista==null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = actividad.getLayoutInflater();
            vista = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fila_colores_spinner, null);                  
        }

        return vista;
    }

    @Override
    public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView,ViewGroup parent) {
        View vista = convertView;       

        //layout for spinner popup

        if (vista==null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = actividad.getLayoutInflater();
            vista = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fila_colores_spinner_popup, null);                    
        }

        return vista;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should apply style to spinner not as theme make this change in xml.

```
 <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatSpinner
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:entries="@array/array_name"
                style="@style/Spinner"/>
```

Add parent to spinner style.

```
<style name="Spinner" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Spinner.Underlined">
        <item name="android:popupBackground">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="android:background">@color/cardview_dark_background</item>
        <item name="android:paddingStart">0dp</item>
        <item name="android:paddingEnd">0dp</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
        <item name="android:backgroundTint">@color/white</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">20sp</item>
        <item name="android:spinnerMode">dropdown</item>

    </style>
```